# Получить доступ к этому классу с помощью js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

у меня вот такое в текстовой разметке:

```
<div>
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

С помощью js (можно и через jquery), я делаю click function нажав на класс two, и мне нужно получить доступ как бы к брату one. Если бы код был таким:

```
<div>
    <div class="one">
       <div class="two"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

То можно было бы получить его вот так:

```
$('.two').parents('.one')
```

Но мне нужно сделать по-другому, возможно ли так сделать?

P.S. Предложений по типу "делай сразу запрос с классу one" не нужны, у меня таких классов с внутренними классами которые я показал выше будет несколько шт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.points').click(function(){
let ar = $(this).parents('.article').find('.article__inner');
if(ar.css('height') === '375px') {
    ar.css('height', 'auto');
} else {
    ar.css('height', '375px');
}
```

});

Comment: решение моего вопроса

Answer (score 2):

Отвечу на чистом JavaScript:

```js
let one = document.querySelector('.two').parentNode.childNodes[0];
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь, но есть вопрос, могу ли я применить функцию css к этой переменной? Ибо у меня почему-то не получается. Например: one.css('display', 'none'); или как правильно в этой ситуации сделать?

Comment: Про pure JS не слышали?
`one.style.display = 'none';`

Comment: main.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (main.js:8)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: Получилось сделать через one.nextElementSibling.style.display, спасибо за помощь

Comment: Хотя нет, при том способе, о котором я написал, стайл добавляется только к первому классу.

Comment: А ко второму вручную добавить не можете разве?)

Comment: К сожалению не получится, я делаю блоки в котором есть текст,  а при нажатии на три точки раскрывается полностью текст

Comment: в том сообщении, "только к первому классу", я имел ввиду к самому первому div-классу

Comment: А через мой способ? Вы его вообще опробовали?

Comment: опробовал, то что изначально скинули - не работает, если получить через nextElementSibling - получаю только первый div класс

Answer (score 1):

Отвечу на чистом jQuery:

```js
$('.bro').on('click', function () {
  console.log($(this).siblings('.bro').html());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div class="bro one">bro one</div>
    <div class="bro two">bro two</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="bro three">bro three</div>
    <div class="bro four">bro four</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за участие, скорее всего этот вариант тоже рабочий, но воспользуюсь своим, еще раз спасибо)